# christmas tree in python language

Tags: python

I'm trying to print Christmas tree like the following:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/up7wN.png)

its my code:

```
 def holidaybush(n):
    z=n-1
    x=1
    for i in range(0,n):
        for i in range(0,z):
            print(' ',end='')
        for i in range(0,x):
            print('*',end='')
        for i in range(0,z):
            print(' ',end='')
        x=x+2
        z=z-1
        print()
 holidaybush(4)
```

with this output:

```
   *   
  ***  
 ***** 
*******
```

but I need also to have a root (‘|’) like following:

```
   *   
  ***  
 ***** 
*******
   |
```

Comment: What problem are you having? We can't just write your code for you; what's the problem with what you've done already?

Comment: need to add a root to the tree, I already added my code and also the proper output above

Comment: No problem, sorry, I just misunderstood your post earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is an extra `print` statement, outside the FOR loop, as the last thing in the `holidaybush` function:

```
    print(" "*(n-2), "|")
```

This will print the "|" character after *n*-2 spaces. This leaves the "root" of the tree underneath the central "*" character,